# Not able to access gitlab internally after reverse proxy setup

Tags: gitlab

Currently I'm getting a `422 The change you requested was rejected` error when trying to login to gitlab.

The only thing I changed was to follow the [official doc on how to setup gitlab behind a reverse proxy](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#external-proxy-and-load-balancer-ssl-termination). The funny thing is, if I access gitlab from the outside via `https`, it works perfectly and to login is possible. But accessing the gitlab instance via the internal lan directly, the above error gets thrown.

Do I miss some configuration for the `nginx` when `http` gets used?

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821162/gitlab-account-acces-error-422-the-change-you-requested-was-rejected and see if it resolves your issue!

Comment: Already saw that discussion. But my problem is that I try to access the instance internally not via the reverse proxy. The route via the reverse proxy works great, but not if I try to the direct way via `http` internal.

Answer (score 0):

Try first and check if your proxy is used when your are using the internal lan.

I usually set

```
no_proxy='localhost,.company.com'
```

That will avoid using the proxy for intranet access.